# MySQL query for multi-column distinct plus an ancillary column condition

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, distinct

Imagine a flat table that tracks game matches in which each game has three participants: an attacker, a defender and a bettor who is wagering on the outcome of the battle between players 1 and 2. The table includes the names of the players and the bettor of each game, as well as the date of the game, the scores of each player, the game venue and the name of the referee. I have included the CREATE sql for some sample data below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `game`;

CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `game_date` text,
  `player_1` text,
  `player_2` text,
  `bettor` text,
  `p1_score` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_score` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `venue` text,
  `referee` text
) 

INSERT INTO `game` VALUES ('2020-04-05','Bob','Kelly','Kevin',100,78,0.2,'TS1','Richard'),('2020-03-06','Jim','Bob','Dave',100,97,1.2,'TS2','Mike'),('2020-02-05','Jim','Bob','Kevin',100,86,0.9,'TS2','Mike'),('2020-01-06','Kelly','Bob','Jim',100,92,1.3,'TS2','Richard'),('2019-12-07','Kelly','Bob','Jim',100,98,1.7,'TS1','Mike'),('2019-11-07','Kelly','Bob','Kevin',78,100,2.1,'TS2','Mike'),('2019-10-08','Kelly','Bob','Kevin',97,100,1.5,'TS1','Mike'),('2019-09-08','Kelly','Jim','Dave',86,100,2.4,'TS1','Richard'),('2019-08-09','Kelly','Jim','Dave',92,100,2.8,'TS2','Mike'),('2019-07-10','Kelly','Jim','Dave',98,100,2.2,'TS2','Mike'),('2019-06-10','Kelly','Jim','Dave',100,78,1.9,'TS2','Richard'),('2019-05-11','Sarah','Jim','Kevin',100,97,2.1,'TS1','Mike'),('2019-04-11','Sarah','Jim','Kevin',100,86,2.1,'TS2','Mike'),('2019-03-12','Sarah','Jim','Kevin',100,92,2.8,'TS1','Mike'),('2019-02-10','Sarah','Jim','Kevin',100,98,1.8,'TS1','Richard');
```

I need a query that returns match info for each unique assembly of match participants... but only for the first match that the three participants ever played in all together, i.e., for the earliest game_date among the matches that all three participated in.

For example, a game where Bob was player 1, Kelly was player two and Kevin was the bettor would constitute a unique threesome. In the data, there is only one such pairing for this threesome so the query would return a row for that one match.

In the case of Sarah as player 1, Jim as player 2 and Kevin as bettor, there are four matches with that threesome and so the query would return only info for the earliest match, i.e., the one 2/10/2019.

Note that in the sample data there are two matches with the threesome 'Kelly','Bob','Jim'. There are also two other matchs with the threesome 'Kelly','Jim','Bob'. These are not the same because Bob and Jim swap places has player 2 and bettor. So the query would return one row for each of them, i.e., the matches dated '12/072019' and '08/09/2019', respectively.

Using DISTINCT, I can return a list of all of the unique player groupings.

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_1, player_2, bettor FROM games;
```

Using GROUP BY, I can return all of the game info for all of the matches the group played in.

```
SELECT * FROM games GROUP BY player_1, player_2, bettor;
```

But I can't figure out how to return all of the game info but only for the earliest game where all three participants played together and in distinct roles in the games.

I have tried sub-queries using MIN() for game_date but that's a loser. I suspect there is perhaps an INNER JOIN solution but I haven't found it yet.

I am grateful for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  If players 1/2/3 play one game and 3/1/2 play another, is that the "same" players?

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff, that is a very good and important question that I did not clarify. I will edit the question to account for that. 

In short, yes, the position of each player as player_1, player_2, or player_3 does matter. Think of it as player 1 is considered the attacker, player 2 is considered the defender and player 3 is a bettor wagering on the outcome between the attacker and the defender.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas -- MySQL version: 8.0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical approach uses a join to a subquery which identifies the earliest games for each trio:

```
SELECT g1.*
FROM games g1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT player_1_name, player_2_name, player_3_name,
           MIN(game_date) AS min_game_date
    FROM games
    GROUP BY player_1_name, player_2_name, player_3_name
) g2
    ON g2.player_1_name = g1.player_1_name AND
       g2.player_2_name = g1.player_2_name AND
       g2.player_3_name = g1.player_3_name AND
       g2.min_game_date = g1.game_date;
```

If you are running MySQL 8+, then the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function provides another option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_1_name, player_2_name,
                                              player_3_name
                                 ORDER BY game_date) rn
    FROM games
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, @tim-biegeleisen! This is really interesting. When I run the query I get what looks like a cartesian product of the entire table, in which the query returns a number of rows for each unique threesome equal to the number of matches times the total number of records in the table. There are games records and so the resulting result set is more than 2,000,000 rows. By the way, MySQL Workbench barked at the query because g1.game_date wasn't included in the base query and the comparison of g2.min_game_date = g1.game_date; failed. So I added game_date to that first JOIN query.

Comment: Setup a demo with sample data and paste the link here.  Use dbfiddle.uk.co as the demo site.

Comment: There's sample data in the question.

Comment: Tim, I regret that I didn't do that when I first posted the question. But, as @barmar has mentioned, I have added sample data to the question.

Comment: If the position of each player matters, i.e. `(1, 2, 3)` is _not_ the same as `(1, 3, 2)`, then my answer should already be working for you.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm not sure why the query wasn't working when I tried it before but I just tried it again and it _did_ work. Sorry for the fire drill. I just accepted your answer. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Tim, one follow up question. There are some records in which the all three players played more than one game together on the same day. In this case, the query returns multiple rows, one for each of the games... because the date is the same for all of the records. If the game_date field also included the time of day of the match, then this wouldn't be a problem... but alas. I thought appending a LIMIT 1 somewhere would fix it... but it doesn't. What is your recommendation for limiting the results to only one record per date?

Comment: @bcrimmins My row number answer doesn't have this problem, and only one row per group is guaranteed to be selected.  For the `GROUP BY` approach, unfortunately you are asking for a third query.  You may first do a select distinct by trio, then aggregate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. That makes sense. I have never encountered the 'ROW_NUMBER' function and so I stuck to your GROUP BY suggestion. But I'm going to dig into it now and learn how to use it. Seems like a powerful concept.